# Trouble with installing Rails on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, osx-yosemite

I followed the guide on [installrails.com](http://installrails.com) and have been stuck at the step installing rails. I tried:

- installing Command Line Tools for Xcode from [apple.com](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2F%2Fdownloads%2Findex.action);
- upgrade most of components(it was at night - don't remember what exactly);
- tried another guide from (can't past it because small reputation, lol), but get equivalent error on the step gem "nokogiri" installing;

I appreciate any suggestions, except to reread those two guides.

This is my log:

```
$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc

Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.4
Fetching: minitest-5.5.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.5.1
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.0
Fetching: rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150301-77493-1tgw3o7.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libxml2/2.9.2)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 6):

An answer a found in [the "Installing Nokogiri" article](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x) on the Nokogiri website.

The trouble was in installing Nokogiri due to the vendored libraries libxml2, libxslt. Here’s how to ignore Nokogiri’s vendored libraries and use your installed system libraries:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running these commands?

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Comment: result: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Comment: First install bundler: 'gem install bundler'

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while installing **`rails version 4.2.0 on MAC OS El Capitan`**, i used following command then installed rails. I worked fine form  me.

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```